# Grocery bill program

Tags: java

trying to write a program where the user is able to insert food price and whether or not it is on sale I'm supposed to use a while loop to see if they have more items or not then display the total tax and final bill. Im trying to find a way to print out all the values inputted by the user in the loop but can't find a way how I got it to ask until the user has no items just need to get all the items printed out in the output

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      double price;
      String decision;
      String item;

      do
      {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Name of the item
      System.out.println("What is the name of your item?");
      item = scan.nextLine(); 

      //Price of the item
      System.out.println("What is the price of your item?");
      price = scan.nextDouble();

      //Whether item is on sale
      System.out.println("Is this item on sale?");
      String sale = scan.next();

      System.out.println("Do you have more items? (Yes/No)");
      decision = scan.next(); 
      }while (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

      System.out.println("Grocery bill");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("purchases");
      System.out.print(item + ": " + "$" + price);

   }
```

so far this is what i have

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a `List` and some class for state e.g.

```
class State{  
  public double price;
  public String decision;
  public String item;
}
```

Then make a new instance from your input and store the result in a list.

At the end loop through the list of items and print their results.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated, creating a separate class to store the item details is a great approach. Since you do not know in advance how many items would be there, you can loop using do-while to collect item details and then keep adding the new item to the List till you are done and then finally pass that list to a method where you print the details and total. Here is a basic implementation that takes details of n items and then prints it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String itemName;
        Double itemPrice;
        String itemOnSale;
        String moreItems;

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do {
                // Name of the item
                System.out.println("What is the name of your item?");
                itemName = scan.next();

                // Price of the item
                System.out.println("What is the price of your item?");
                itemPrice = scan.nextDouble();

                // Whether item is on sale
                System.out.println("Is this item on sale?(Yes/No)");
                itemOnSale = scan.next();

                System.out.println("Do you have more items? (Yes/No)");
                moreItems = scan.next();

                items.add(new Item(itemName, itemPrice, itemOnSale));

            } while (moreItems.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        } finally {
            printBill(items);
        }

    }

    private static void printBill(List<Item> items) {
        double total = 0.00;

        System.out.println("**************  Grocery Bill  ******************");

        System.out.println("*** ITEM NAME **** ITEM PRICE **** ON SALE ? ****");

        for (Item item : items) {
            System.out.printf("    %s             %.2f           %s           \n", item.itemName, item.price,
                    item.itemOnSale);
            total += item.price;
        }

        System.out.println("************************************************");
        System.out.println("Total :" + total);
    }
}

class Item {

    String itemName;
    double price;
    String itemOnSale;

    public Item(String itemName, double price, String itemOnSale) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.price = price;
        this.itemOnSale = itemOnSale;
    }

}
```